# One of the tables is not being generated by JPA/hibernate when I use ddl-auto=create

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create` set, and most of my tables are being generated. *One* is not! I know this must be something stupid, and I'm hoping it's common enough that someone will recognize the problem.

Here is the entity whose table is not being created (without the imports).

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ImageSize {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "imagesizeseq", sequenceName = "IMAGE_SIZE_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "imagesizeseq")
    private Integer imageSizeId;

    private String Size;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "imageSize")
    private List<ImageData> imageDatas;

}
```

Here is the entity with a relationship to the missing table

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ImageData {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "imagedataseq", sequenceName = "IMAGE_DATA_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "imagedataseq")
    private Integer imageDataId;

    @Lob
    private byte[] imageData;   //TODO: make this java.sql.Blob rather than byte[]; see p 101 in hibernate bk

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "IMAGE_SIZE_ID")
    private ImageSize imageSize;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "IMAGE_ID")
    private Image image;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "MIME_TYPE_ID")
    private MimeType mimeType;

}
```

Comment: Is there an error in the logs or is it just not created?

Comment: Yes, there was an error in the console. I completely missed that. The problem was a reserved word I think. The console error just said 'invalid identifier' but changing from 'size' ('Size' really; a double mistake) to 'imageSize' fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Consider adding your solution as answer for future references.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was a reserved word. The console error just said 'invalid identifier' right after trying to create the image_size table (the missing one). I changed a field in the image_size table from 'size' to 'imageSize' and that fixed the problem.